# Regular expression for removing +1 code from international numbers in php

Tags: php, regex

I have set of strings of numbers , and want to remove + 1  where it is found.

i have this set

```
$arr="605-2969,
408-605-2969,
+ 1-408-605-2969,
+ 1 (408) 605-2969,
(408) 605-2969,
(408)-605-2969,
14086052969,
4086052969,
6052969";
```

and want to remove + 1 from it.

i have tried following code:

```
$str = ltrim($arr, '+ 1');
var_dump($str);
```

but this is not working.Please help me out or give me an idea to solve this.
i want the output like in array:

"4086632208,4088072425,4086052969,..."

Comment: Y not str_replace

Comment: how it is done by str_replace. i have tried but not getting output

Comment: something like this:-https://eval.in/659776

Comment: yes need something like this but can we get numbers without extra symbols and + 1

Comment: Is your question about removing all special characters, or just `+ 1`? Maybe you want `preg_replace`.

Comment: yes both need to be removed. Yes i am trying with preg_replace.

Comment: Why doesn't it say that in the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str_replace()` as:

```
$str = str_replace('+ 1','',$arr);

var_dump($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace()` to remove everything that matches a pattern. The pattern will match `+ 1` and any character other than numbers and comma.

```
$str = preg_replace('/\+ 1|[^\d,]/', '', $arr);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/q9LWjd)